# Dúvida sobre a função map

Tags: front-end, typescript, angular, semantic-ui

Eu tenho esse objeto

```
    {
    "alunos": [
        {
            "aluno": {
                "id": 1,
                "nome": "Genevieve Sipes",
                "status": "Ativo"
            },
            "mensalidade": {
                "status": "Débito"
            }
        },
        {
            "aluno": {
                "id": 2,
                "nome": "Greyson Herman",
                "status": "Ativo"
            },
            "mensalidade": {
                "status": "Débito"
            }
        },
        {
            "aluno": {
                "id": 3,
                "nome": "Yessenia Emmerich",
                "status": "Ativo"
            },
            "mensalidade": {
                "status": "Débito"
            }
        },]
}
```

E preciso transformar ele em algo assim

```
[
   {
      nome: 'Genevieve Sipes',
      status: 'Débito',
   },

]
```

Tentei fazer assim, mas não deu certo, alguém sabe como fazer ?

```
this.names = this.students.map(function(student){
    console.log(student.aluno.nome);
      return student.aluno.nome;
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu não sei, se realmente é necessário criar outro layout dessas informações só para imprimir, mas, um exemplo de como seria uma forma de aplicar esse novo *layout de dados*:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.alunos = {
    "alunos": [{
        "aluno": {
          "id": 1,
          "nome": "Genevieve Sipes",
          "status": "Ativo"
        },
        "mensalidade": {
          "status": "Débito"
        }
      },
      {
        "aluno": {
          "id": 2,
          "nome": "Greyson Herman",
          "status": "Ativo"
        },
        "mensalidade": {
          "status": "Débito"
        }
      },
      {
        "aluno": {
          "id": 3,
          "nome": "Yessenia Emmerich",
          "status": "Ativo"
        },
        "mensalidade": {
          "status": "Débito"
        }
      },
    ]
  };
  $scope.names = $scope.alunos.alunos.map(function(student)
  {    
      return {nome:student.aluno.nome, status:student.mensalidade.status};
  });      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in names">{{item.nome}} - {{item.status}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Na forma original do layout também dá pra imprimir as informações do mesmo jeito:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.alunos = {
    "alunos": [{
        "aluno": {
          "id": 1,
          "nome": "Genevieve Sipes",
          "status": "Ativo"
        },
        "mensalidade": {
          "status": "Débito"
        }
      },
      {
        "aluno": {
          "id": 2,
          "nome": "Greyson Herman",
          "status": "Ativo"
        },
        "mensalidade": {
          "status": "Débito"
        }
      },
      {
        "aluno": {
          "id": 3,
          "nome": "Yessenia Emmerich",
          "status": "Ativo"
        },
        "mensalidade": {
          "status": "Débito"
        }
      },
    ]
  }; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in alunos.alunos">{{item.aluno.nome}} - {{item.mensalidade.status}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: É que eu to usando  o autocomplete do semantic e na hora de passar os dados ele  assim                                                                                                        $('.ui.search')
  .search({
    source : content,
    searchFields   : [
      'nome'
    ],
    searchFullText: false
  })

Comment: @MateusHenrique, entendi, a solução foi útil para você, resolveu seu problema?